# In a Java project which file format to be used for Data Dictionary will give best performance?

Tags: java, xml, yaml

Using which type comes as Best practice .

For eg. XML , CSV , YML .

Edit : 
This is a UI Automation Java Project employing webdriver. By Data Dictionary I mean the repo of data to be used in Tests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest using JSON Table Schema its easy to manintain: http://www.dataprotocols.org/en/latest/json-table-schema.html

It's:

1. JSON-based
2. Extendable

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is no best practice, and without knowing what you mean by "data dictionary" there is no answer possible.

However, it is surely true that you are worrying about performance way too early.  Pick the one that's easiest for you to work with and make sure to encapsulate that choice in an adapter class that can be replaced to read/write any format.

When your application is finished, *if performance problems can be traced to the format you chose* then try a different one.

Comment: This is a UI Automation Java Project employing webdriver. By Data Dictionary I mean the repo of data to be used in Tests.